# Is there any reason that the package statement in java should be at the beginning?

Tags: java, package

I am beginning with the Java Programming language; and I have a simple question:

In java packages, if the class is part of a package, the package statement must be the first line in the source code file, before any import statements that may be present.

Is there any valuable reason for the package statement should be at the beginning?

Comment: Is there any reason it should _not_ be the first statement? Where would _you_ put it and why?

Answer (score 9):

Is there a reason? Sure, the language designers made a design decision that it had to be at the start of the compilation unit. From [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3):

> CompilationUnit is the goal symbol (§2.1) for the syntactic grammar (§2.3) of Java programs. It is defined by the following productions:
>
> ```
> CompilationUnit:
>     [PackageDeclaration] {ImportDeclaration} {TypeDeclaration}
> ```

So, you've got to have zero or one package declarations, then zero or more import declarations, then zero or more type declarations.

Could it have been different? Absolutely; but it is the way it is.

Comment: You have to admit the irony in that. Some other user told you some days back: "you should write more answers"; and now we both write pretty similar answers; almost down to the quote that we make ... and you do that 30 seconds before me, and all the upvotes go to you ... but well, have mine as well.

Comment: @GhostCat I believe the phrase is "be careful what you wish for" ;)

Comment: Well, when I made the "elite" badge and saw that you got there some days before me, I asked the universe if I could speed up pulling in the remaining 100 days for legendary; and so far, that part is working out nicely. So I really do not complain ;-)

Answer (score 2):

See the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.3):

> CompilationUnit:
>
> [PackageDeclaration] {ImportDeclaration} {TypeDeclaration}
>
> A compilation unit consists of three parts, each of which is optional...

And to be precise: you do **not** need to have the package statement on the first line. The when you want to have a package statement, that statement must be the first line that not empty or a comment/empty (unless, as correctly pointed out ... in the very special [package-info.java](https://www.intertech.com/Blog/whats-package-info-java-for/)).

The underlying reason is probably to make implementing the Java compiler easier to do - as you simply know the enclosing package name when reaching the first class declaration.

That is all there is to this.

Comment: Except in package-info.java where the first non-comment, non-empty line could be an annotation ;)

Comment: I would say that an annotation is part of the declaration/statement it is annotating, so @Thomas's comment seems obsolete to me.

Comment: Probably that is some *cultural* thingy. @Thomas and myself are both Germans; and nothing less than 100% perfection is good enough ;-)

Comment: Haha yeah, that might be the reason ;)

Answer (score 0):

Conceptual there is no reason. You may parse the whole file first and build your in memory representation later as you like. But I think the *valuable reason* you are asking for is when writing a parser it is easier if you know the package early on, because everything else should be done in the context of that package.