# Why is the "package log" is underlined as error?

Tags: java

Hello users at Stack Overflow

**(Quick Info: I use Eclipse 2018-09, I'm using Java 8)**

I have a question about my coding. It's a little bit outdated (Java 8), but the thing I ask for is why is my coding underlined in red.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

package log;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your username");
        String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your password");

        if (

                username != null && password != null &&
                (

                    (username.equals("gkic17") && password.equals("irena46")) ||
                    (username.equals("dm") && password.equals("me21mar")) ||
                    (username.equals("citizenzap") && password.equals("guestboy19"))
                )
           )
        {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in!" );
        }   else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username or password! Try again later." );
        }
    }
}
```

In the beginning at `package log;`, it's underlined red. Here are the errors.

Console Error

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:`

`at log.Login.main(Login.java:7)`

Error on IDE

`Syntax error on token "package", import expected` (I'm not sure what import it wants, though)

Thanks,
CitizenZap

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43935672/is-there-any-reason-that-the-package-statement-in-java-should-be-at-the-beginnin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Creating a Package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/createpkgs.html):

> The package statement (for example, package graphics;) must be the
>   first line in the source file. There can be only one package statement
>   in each source file, and it applies to all types in the file.

So your code should be:

```
package log;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String username = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your username");
        String password = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your password");

        if (username != null && password != null
                && ((username.equals("gkic17") && password.equals("irena46"))
                        || (username.equals("dm") && password.equals("me21mar"))
                        || (username.equals("citizenzap") && password.equals("guestboy19")))) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Logged in!");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect username or password! Try again later.");
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Take care of [code style guide](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), your code will be easier to read and maintain

Comment: Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it!